# I need to enter a specific value at a specific location in a table using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to enter a specific value at a specific location in a table using selenium webdriver.
 Please help me with that. I am using this

```
List<WebElement> efforts =  driver.findElement(By.id("tblProjectsTagged")).findElement(By.className("effort2-body")).findElements(By.className("effort3"));
List<WebElement> days =  driver.findElement(By.id("dateSlider")).findElements(By.className(".item.slick-slide.slick-active"));//.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
System.out.println(days.size());
System.out.println(efforts.size());
 int i = 0;

 // Get the column where the quantity is listed
 for(WebElement header :efforts)
 {
     i++;
     if(header.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Test Execution-Automated(8212939)"))
     {
         System.out.println("s");
         break;
```

Comment: good to have HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the HTML code of the particular table where you are trying to enter the value?

Usually when you are trying to put a value into a particular location in a table it is better to select the particular  tag using Xpath and then enter value there.
For example if the HTML code is as follows:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type='text'>
    </td>
    <td>
    Enter Your Name
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here you can select the following text input using

> WebElement
>   Element1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[id='table1']/tr/td[1]/input");
>   Element1.sendKeys("Input Value");

Comment: If this doesn't help you please post the HTML code table you are trying to automate then I will be able to help you better.